# Homebrew cant find otool or clang

Tags: python, clang, homebrew, otool

I am trying to install Python 3 using homebrew, but it fails with an error. When I run `brew doctor` it says:

> Error: Failure while executing: /usr/bin/otool -L
>   /usr/bin/install_name_tool

How do I fix this?

Comment: Assuming this is on OS X, have you installed the Xcode command line tools? There are some useful instructions here: http://railsapps.github.io/xcode-command-line-tools.html

Comment: Use quote instead of code for one-liner log.